# Generate random probability based on the data size in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I want to generate a non-uniform random sample using a range and specific size using Numpy as follows:

`np.random.choice(m=5, n, p=[0.1, 0, 0.3, 0.6, 0])`,

However, I want to obtain `p` randomly based on the size of `m` automatically without manually writing `p=[0.1, 0, 0.3, 0.6, 0])` as above. How to do that in Numpy?

Comment: [`np.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) does not have a parameter `m`.

Comment: Do you mean that `p` should be a list of random `float` values, of length `m`, that sums to 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to get a list of random `float` values, of length `m`, that sums to `1`:

```
m = 5
values = [np.random.rand() for _ in range(m)]
p = [v/sum(values) for v in values]
```

However, since `values` are all in the range 0-1, the weighting is more even than you may be after. You'd have to specify more about what type of distribution you're looking for, to get a more specific answer.

Comment: Thank you it makes sense. However, when I try to use like this ```np.random.choice(m, foo.shape[0], p)```, there is a warning ```A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead``` . And for specific distribution, e.g., uniform, normal, should I need to adjust ```p = [v/sum(values) for v in values]```

Comment: I get the sense that things don't make as much sense as you say they do. Apparently you are using `pandas` although your question makes no mention of this. Your question also doesn't mention `foo`, so I can't answer why this issue is occurring. The question you asked is answered, if you have further issues, please expand your question or ask a new one. The example I gave has a uniform distribution, for other distributions, you need to provide more information on what you need (in the question, not in the comments on the answer).